# LWJGL Window Closes Even When In update Loop

Tags: java, lwjgl

My Window Closes Even When I called Display.Update in the loop, It Just Closes Here's My Code:

```
package com.kgt.platform.name;

import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

public class Game {


public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{


    Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(640, 480));
    Display.create();

    while(Display.isCloseRequested())
    {

        Display.update();
        Display.sync(60);
    }
    Display.destroy();
}

}
```

It's Really Weird The Windows Closes After It Runs For a Sec,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in your while loop condition, it should be :

```
while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){...}
```

You should read it like "While the Display does *not* require the display/window to close, do the instructions in the while loop".

Hope it helps.

Comment: Also note, it is generally a good idea to have a boolean value in that loop, in case you want to programmatically be able to shut down as well.